# How Do i fix this error: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: laravel, flutter, exception

I keep getting the following error

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
#0      UserController.getUserInfo (package:smarthnb/controllers/user_controller.dart:29:48)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is a my User Model

```
class UserModel{
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String phone;
  int orderCount;

  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.phone,
    required this.orderCount,
  });
  factory UserModel.fromJson (Map< String, dynamic> json){
    return UserModel(
        id:json['id'],
        name:json['f_name'],
        email:json['email'],
        phone:json['phone'],
        orderCount:json['order_count'],
    );
  }
```

Here is my User Controller for reference

```
class UserController extends GetxController implements GetxService {
  final UserRepo userRepo;

  UserController({
    required this.userRepo,
  });

  bool _isLoading = false;
  late UserModel _userModel;

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  UserModel get userModel =>_userModel;

  Future<ResponseModel> getUserInfo() async{
    _isLoading = true;
    update();
    Response response = await userRepo.getUserInfo();
    late ResponseModel responseModel;

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      _userModel = UserModel.fromJson(response.body);
      responseModel = ResponseModel(true,"successfully");

    }
```

I think it has to do with how I collect information from the server, Json format info and it's conversion that is, though I can't pin point the exact solution, this is just what I think, I'm  open to correction no doubt.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648436/exception-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-mapstring-dynamic

Comment: you have decode the response  try this. 


 _userModel = UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648436/exception-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-mapstring-dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not parsing the `response.body` to Map as it comes as a string from the API and to covert it to the model you will need to pass the Map in the `UserModel.fromJson()` method as it accepts `Map< String, dynamic>` in your model's factory method.